# Data Modelling Best Practice in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-modeling

This question may have been asked multiple times and in multiple ways. And I've not been able to find a satisfactory answer.

Given that data in Snowflake is organised in a columnar format and regardless of Data Modelling approach (3NF, Dimensional, Data Vault), what is the best practice when designing data model in Snowflake?

Any recommendation or suggestion of online resource on this topic is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: _regardless of data modelling approach, what is the best practice for designing data model_ ???? Regardless of that contradictory question, you need to specify your requirements. Analytics? Probably dimensional. Ingestion/ODS? Probably data vault. 3NF often doesn't come up as a choice because that is primarily for OLTP and Snowflake is not really an OLTP database.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. "Regardless of data modelling approach" = take your pick (DV, Dimensional). Assuming that DV is used, "what is the best practice for designing data model" = is there anything specific to Snowflake that a DV Data Modeller should be mindful of?

Comment: I assume Snowflake would have a whitepaper that would help you

Answer (score 2):

Given that Snowflake is largely a MPP Columnar Store (but yes - with a twist), the content of this paper should largely hold true. And credit to its author (Sudershan Srinivasan), it is very well-written.

https://docplayer.net/2885379-Data-modeling-applying-relevant-data-modeling-techniques-to-mpp-columnar-stores-a-point-of-view-author-sudershan-srinivasan.html

Although it covers mostly dimensional modelling technique, some suggestions such as denormalizing instead of building snowflake dimensions / centipede facts would apply in DV and 3NF. That is, rethink your need to normalize if your objective is to avoid repeated data and thereby reduce storage consumption.

But if anyone has any other resource or thoughts to share, pls do share them.

Answer (score 0):

The question you have asked is itself tricky. For agility, flexibility, and scalability I would choose Data Vault. Please follow the link and follow Kent Graziano. https: https://www.snowflake.com/blog/support-multiple-data-modeling-approaches-with-snowflake/

If my answer helps you please mark this answer is useful.

Comment: Thanks, Anil. Assuming that DV is used, is there anything specific to Snowflake that a DV Data Modeller should be mindful of?

Comment: Hi Des.Lim, there is no specific to Snowflake. You can do whatever you want and your client wants.